# Android Speech recognition redirecting based on keyword (think: navigate to Warsaw)

Tags: android, keyword, speech-recognition

Is there any way to register with android speech recognition service and make it hijack all the input that begins with specified keyword? Like for example now on modern android device if you hold down search button then speech detection is initialized and if you say something that begins with "navigate to" then navigation app is started instead of browser. Can this be done for arbitrary app?